# Troubleshooting Proprietary NVIDIA 319.49 Driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

Though I would prefer to use the open-source nouveau drivers, the support for my 485M chip has not proved fruitful in the past.

Because NVIDIA's driver repository is somewhat dated, I downloaded the latest (recommended, NOT beta) driver install package/script from the official site. I then booted into recovery and ran the installer with no hiccups save for one warning regarding the failure to run a "distribution-provided pre-install script." The install completed successfully with no warnings or errors, and I was sure to build the kernel module and even ran `update-initramfs -u` to ensure a proper boot. However, after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB, all that is presented is a blank screen with a blinking underscore cursor in the top left corner.

After searching around a bit, I've learned that others experiencing problems with the proprietary drivers in Ubuntu (and Mint) are often presented with TTY error screens during boot displaying some level of verbosity concerning displays, or experience a full graphical boot plagued by blinking/flashing images. I also learned that some problems may be present with the proprietary driver on notebook systems.

Has anyone had a similar experience with this or previous version of the NVIDIA proprietary driver on Ubuntu/Debian-based [or otherwise] Linux systems? Does anything come to mind that might resolve the issue?

I am running a 64-bit system under Ubuntu 13.04 with an Intel Core i7-2920XM chipset and a NVIDIA GTX 485M graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very strange problem that seemingly resolved itself. Or rather, something I did resolved it. Possible factors that may have contributed to its resolution are:

- The reinstallation of the `nvidia-common` package
- The reinstallation of the entire driver (though I did this multiple times)
- The running of `nvidia-xconfig`, `nvidia-modprobe`, and `nvidia-persistence`
- Running the tested proprietary driver listed in the Additional Drivers tab of the Software Properties application before the final reinstallation of the current driver.